# Keep order of installation in pip freeze

Tags: python, package, pip

Quick question.

Is there a way to ensure that `pip freeze > requirements.txt` keeps the order in which the packages were installed? This is an issue for me because I continuously get something like this in `requirements.txt`:

```
matplotlib==1.1.1
numpy==1.6.2
```

So an error occurs when I try to install using `pip install -r requirements.txt` because numpy is a dependency of matplotlib, so I have to install manually numpy first and then rerun `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Is there any fix on that?

**UPDATE**: In response to mechmind, I installed matplotlib and numpy in Ubuntu 12.04 using pip with virtualenv --distribute myenv. After installation, I got this freeze file:

```
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.28
matplotlib==1.1.1
numpy==1.6.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Then when I try to reinstall in another virtual environment I get the following error:

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

                 numpy: no

                        * You must install numpy 1.4 or later to build

                        * matplotlib.
```

So maybe it's dependent on the system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just tried `pip` with `numpy` and `matplotlib` and `pip` correctly resolved dependency checks - numpy built first.
Tried on old stock pip from ubuntu 10.10.

**EDIT**: After playing with `pip` and `virtualenv`, i realized that dependency check actually works only when that dependencies was discovered, i.e. when package was installed, removed and installed again.

So actual solution will involve reordering of packages in requrements file (for simple case when there are only two packages with wrong order, you can just reverse requirements file: `sort -r | xargs pip install`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did another test but I got the same error. See my update for more details.

Comment: Tried with virtualenv, got the same result as you. Probably `pip` cached dependency of installed packages somewhere. So, if you have trouble only with these two packages, i suggest dead-simple solution - just reverse requirements file, i.e. `sort -r requrements.txt | xargs pip install`

Comment: Clever. I think that should work but in any realistic situation, it will create another dependencies issues. For example, in my case, scipy is requiring numpy.

Comment: So, only explicit reordering can help you.

Comment: Well, of course, but that's hardly a good solution, particularly when other package managers resolve dependencies. I was expecting that pip could also do that.